# Finding maximum value in a column and return row number

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to find out which row number contains the maximum value.

I have tried something like this:

```
specimen = loadtxt('dataFile.dat')
stress = specimen[:,3]*(1+(specimen[:,2]/100))
strain = log(1+ specimen[:,2]/100)*100

m = max(stress) #<-- at which row??
print m
print row
```

Comment: Please specify you are using Numpy, because that's important context for answering this question.  I'd recommend against using wildcard import (`from numpy import *`), since this makes the code harder to read and will shadow several built-ins with NumPy functions.

Comment: Sorry Sven. I am a beginner at python. I will try to remember it till next time. And thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumPy's [`argmax()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) functyion or method.

```
stress.argmax()
```

will return the indices of the maximum value in the array.  You can optionally specify and axis to get all maximum indices along the chosen axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
maxima = [max(row) for row in stress]  # Find the max values in each row
m = max(maxima)                        # Find the absolute max value in the array
for k, rowmax in enumerate(maxima):
    if rowmax == m:                    # Find which row contains the absolute max value
        row = k
        break

print m
print row
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Svens' method was a bit easier.